# Function parameter evaluates to undefined

Tags: javascript, html

When dynamically creating an element of type `select`, there are two problems when setting the onclick method:

1. It is impossible to simply set the `onclick` with `element.onclick="updateInput(this.articleIndex)";`

This results in a final HTML tag where no `onclick` is shown at all.

When set by `e.setAttribute("onclick","updateInput(this.articleIndex)");`, it does appear in the final HTML. And the `updateInput` method does get called.

2. However the functionality seems to be broken, as the argument always evaluates to `undefined`

Here a simple example of my problems:

```
var selectElem = document.createElement("select");
selElem.id="articleSelector_"+this.articleIndex; 
console.log("the index of the article is " + this.articleIndex);
selElem.setAttribute("onclick","updateInput(this.articleIndex);");
//selElem.onclick="updateInput(this.articleIndex)"; //this does not work
```

The log shows the correct number. Inside the `updateInput` method, the argument is of value `undefined` instead of the number previously shown in the log.

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* that `this` depends on the context where you access it. The `this` in the `console.log` ain't the same object as `this` in your `onclick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching handlers with pure Javascript, and not with HTML, without `onclick = "...` (which is as bad as `eval`).

The `this` in your script refers to the calling context of the function - what is it?

You might want:

```
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
  updateInput(this.articleIndex);
});
```

(arrow functions retain the `this` of their surrounding scope)

Comment: That did it. Struggled a bit because it is named "click" instead of "onclick" and "keyup" instead of "onkeyup" etc. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> it is impossible to simply set the onclick with element.onclick="updateInput(this.articleIndex)";

What that code does is it assigns the string `"updateInput(this.articleIndex)"` to the `onclick` which makes no sense and certainly not what you want.

Even if you remove the quotes:

```
element.onclick = updateInput(this.articleIndex);
```

It is still incorrect because it assigns the result of the `updateInput()` function to the `onclick` which is again not what you want.

You need to assign a function name to the `onclick` like this:

```
element.onclick = updateInput;
```

However, this doesn't allow you to pass a parameter as you wish. To do so, you need to use an anonymous function:

```
element.onclick = function() {
    updateInput(this.articleIndex)
};
```

> When set by e.setAttribute("onclick","updateInput(this.articleIndex)");, it does appear in the final HTML. And the updateInput method does get called.

This works because it sets the attribute `onclick` and it is a string type, so everything is correct. It is equivalent to using the anonymous function above. The only difference is `this`, which in this case refers to the element itself, while in the above code it depends on the context that the code appears in. That's why in this case the argument always evaluates to `undefined` because the `select` element doesn't have an `articleIndex` property.

Comment: Thank you @Racil Hilan for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value of the context `this` when that element is clicked, the context `this` is not available anymore at that moment.

**You have two ways to solve this problem:**

- You can use the function `addEventListener` to bind the event click, and bind the function/handler with the desired context `this`:

The function `bind` binds a specific context to a function.

```
selElem.addEventListener('click', updateInput.bind(this));

function updateInput() {
    console.log(this.articleIndex);
}
```

- As you need a specific value, you can use data attributes.  That way, you don't need to worry about the context `this`.

```
selElem.dataset.articleIndex = this.articleIndex;
selElem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateInput(this.dataset.articleIndex); // Here you can get that value.
});
```